# SQL Server: Categorize data within table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to compare a table to itself in SQL Server 2012.  The table consists of among other columns Client Name, Client Number and Fiscal Year.  Within the table there is data for FY15 and FY16 and clients can repeat multiple times.

I am trying to add a column to the table that will stipulate whether the client in each row is either "New" (exists in FY16 but not FY15), "Existing" (exists in FY16 and FY15), or "Lost" (exists in FY15 but not FY16).

I've tried joining the table to itself and using case statements but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c1.Name, c1.Number, c1.FiscalYear,   
       CASE 
          WHEN c1.FiscalYear = 2015 AND c2.FiscalYear = 2016 THEN 'Existing'
          WHEN c1.FiscalYear = 2015 AND c2.FiscalYear IS NULL THEN 'Lost'
          WHEN c1.FiscalYear = 2016 AND c2.FiscalYear = 2015 THEN 'Existing'
          WHEN c1.FiscalYear = 2016 AND c2.FiscalYear IS NULL THEN 'New'
       END AS category   
FROM clients AS c1
LEFT JOIN clients AS c2 
   ON c1.Name = c2.Name AND 
      ((c1.FiscalYear = 2015 AND c2.FiscalYear = 2016) OR
      (c1.FiscalYear = 2016 AND c2.FiscalYear = 2015))
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cacb5/3)

If you just want to get category per client name, then you can use a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Name,
       CASE 
          WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT FiscalYear) = 2 THEN 'Existing'
          WHEN SUM(FiscalYear = 2015) > 0 AND SUM(FiscalYear = 2016) = 0 THEN 'Lost'
          WHEN SUM(FiscalYear = 2016) > 0 AND SUM(FiscalYear = 2015) = 0 THEN 'New'
       END AS category   
FROM clients
WHERE FiscalYear IN (2015, 2016)
GROUP BY Name
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cacb5/10)

You also can use the above query to perform an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE clients
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Name,
         CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT FiscalYear) = 2 THEN 'Existing'
            WHEN SUM(FiscalYear = 2015) > 0 AND SUM(FiscalYear = 2016) = 0 THEN 'Lost'
            WHEN SUM(FiscalYear = 2016) > 0 AND SUM(FiscalYear = 2015) = 0 THEN 'New'
         END AS category   
  FROM clients
  WHERE FiscalYear IN (2015, 2016)
  GROUP BY Name 
) AS t ON clients.name = t.name
SET clients.category = t.category
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59f7d5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Version with update:

```
update customer 
set status = case when 
   (select count(*) from customer C2 where C2. ClientName = customer.ClientName and C2.Year in (2015,2016) ) = 2 then 'Existing' 
   when  
      (select count(*) from customer C2 where C2.clientName = customer.ClientName and C2.Year = 2015  ) = 1 then  'Lost'
   when 
     (select count(*) from customer C2 where C2.clientName = customer.ClientName and C2.Year in (2016) ) = 1 then  'New'
     end;
```

Sample in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/adfb1/1/1) here